# Start a new scene when the button is clicked?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I need to start a new scene when the button is clicked, but when I click on it - nothing happens; what's the problem?

```
public class Options : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button button;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void LoadOptions()
{
  button.GetComponent<Button>();
   button.onClick.AddListener(LoadScene);
   
}
// loading scene
void LoadScene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Options");
}
}
```

When I click on it - nothing happens; what's the problem?
I added a scene named "Options" to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this just add the script in an empty game object which is the parent of the button and add this:

```
public void ChangeScene()
{
SceneManager.LoadScene("Options");
}
```

Then in the button add the empty gameObject in the **OnClick**, then select **ChangeScene**, if the button is raycasted well and you have nothing that blocks it, it will work fine

If you do not want to use scene name you can `LoadScene(0)` but in the build settings drag the scene to see its index